# Can you guess what I am?

Tags: riddle

> I am in the sky, and in your pie.
>   I can not be touched.
>   When an item that stores me is stolen I am never chosen.

**What am I?**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Is this from an ongoing contest?

Answer (score 3):

You are a:

> hole

"I am in the sky, and in your pie."

> There is a hole in the ozone layer.

"I can not be touched."

> Holes are not physical.

"When an item that stores me is stolen I am never chosen."

> Stolen bags with holes in them probably don't have money in them anymore after it all fell through the holes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> The color Blue

I am in the sky, and in your pie.

> The sky is blue, and Blueberry pie is a common sort of pie

I can not be touched.

> Colors are intangible

When an item that stores me is stolen I am never chosen.

> a little bit tricky, but what 'stores' an intangible thing like the color blue? Perhaps a painting? When a painting is stolen, the Police are often called (chosen, if you will), and Police forces (at least in the US) are often called blue for their uniforms (Think NYPD Blue, or 'the boys in blue').

Answer (score -2):

Well, with due credits to R.Dye, here is another one

> A hollow

As, it is

> there in the sky and pie. Also we cannot touch it. Usually purse/wallet that contains coins with holes is stolen, notes are preferred over **nickels**.